# Application.ApplicationExit is unexpectedly raised a second time

Tags: c#, winforms, events, exit

Closing the main `Form` with `.Close`, `ControlBox`, etc., and subsequently calling `Application.Exit()` causes the `ApplicationExit` event to be raised twice. However, if the `Form` is closed by calling `Application.Exit()` first, the event is only raised once.

[Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.applicationexit(v=vs.110).aspx) says:

> Occurs when the application is about to shut down.

Reviewing [source code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Application.cs,086e8e3251c84fde) reveals a private `RaiseExit` method that is only called from `ThreadContext.Dispose(bool PostQuit)` and is decorated with the comment:

> Called by the last thread context before it shuts down.

This apparently is not entirely correct. It will be called for any `ThreadContext` that does not have a MessageLoop running.

**Where is the extra 'ghost' `ThreadContext` coming from when the application is closed via the `Form`.**

---

Clarification of "ghost `ThreadContext`":
As expected, a `ThreadContext` is created and a message loop started for the thread when `Application.Run(new MainForm())` executes. When the form is closed, that message loop is shutdown and the `ThreadContext` is disposed which appropriately raises the `ApplicationExit` event. However, somewhere in the shutdown, a new `ThreadContext` is created without a message loop and results in `ApplicationExit` being fired a second time if `Application.Exit()` is subsequently called.

---

Program.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    static class Program
    {
        private static int _ApplicationExitEventCount = 0;
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.ApplicationExit += Application_ApplicationExit;

            Application.Run(new MainForm());

            //Just to make sure not suffering a race.
            Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));

            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) //A loop to show it's not dependent on the times Application.Exit() is called.
            {
                //Application.Exit() Disposes the ThreadContext so a call to MessageLoop creates a new one.
                //Uncomment the following line to show that ApplicationExit will be raised for each itteration.
                //Console.WriteLine("Application.MessageLoop: {0}", Application.MessageLoop);

                Application.Exit();
            }

            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("ApplicationExit event count: {0}", _ApplicationExitEventCount.ToString()));
        }

        private static void Application_ApplicationExit(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _ApplicationExitEventCount++;
        }
    }
}
```

MainForm just has a single button that calls `Application.Exit`. The loops around `Application.Exit()` are to demonstrate this behavior isn't as simple as the event being raised each time `Application.Exit()` is called.

MainForm.cs

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class MainForm : Form
    {
        public MainForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //Application.Exit(); //NoOp
        }
        //Loop to show this isn't dependent on the total number of times
        //Application.Exit() is called.
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                Application.Exit();
            }
        }
        protected override void OnFormClosing(FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("OnFormClosing called.");
            base.OnFormClosing(e);
        }
        protected override void OnFormClosed(FormClosedEventArgs e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("OnFormClosed called.");
            base.OnFormClosed(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `FormClosingEventArgs` has a property `Cancel` which must be set prior to calling base.OnFormClosing.

Comment: Ok, everything you posted is true. What's the question?

Comment: @t0mm13b This isn't about canceling a Close. It's about what happens if Application.Exit() happens to be called after Application.Run(...) returns. It behaves differently in the two cases.

Comment: More in with what @IvanStoev mentioned, is this causing you any issues to your app?

Comment: @IvanStoev The question is why does it behave this way and, more to the point, what is causing a new `ThreadContext` - without a message loop - to be created after the form is closed and `Application.Run(...)` has returned.  Sure, a flag can be used to see if 'ApplicationExit' handler has already run but I'd like to know what I'm actually missing because It's strange that the event is being raised twice.

Comment: @fujiFX The problem originally surfaced dealing with multiple threads that could call `Application.Exit()` and my cleanup code was getting called twice. The multithreading was the first suspect but it still occurs after everything was removed.

Comment: I ran the code you posted, and the output showed the event handler was called only once. So, whatever's going on, there is something about your scenario that's important but which you haven't included in your post. Possibly the .NET version you're using? Anyway, it's not really clear what your question is exactly, but for sure you'll need to do some more investigation so that you can more precisely nail down how to reproduce the issue.

Comment: What is causing it - [ThreadContext.FromCurrent](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Application.cs,cb43f8b655b5d94b) call after `Dispose`, i.e. by virtually every `Application` "property" / method. Why it behave differently - because of the implementation difference when called from inside message loop vs from outside. In general, try to avoid any `Application` calls after `Application.Run` returns.

Comment: @PeterDuniho Thank your for taking the time to repro.  I've run the code on 2 different machines compiled against .Net versions 4.6.1,  4.5.1,  4.0, and 2.0 all from VS2015 Community Edition. Curious what is different between our environments.

Comment: @IvanStoev Searching through the source, I can't find when or where `ThreadContext.FromCurrent` is being called after `Dispose` and there doesn't appear to be any reason for it to be. Dealing with the consequences of this behavior is fairly trivial so at this point it's really just an exercise in curiosity because of the unexpected behavior.

Comment: @JamesDurda As you mentioned in the provided example, in order to duplicate the issue we had to uncomment the `MessageLoop` property. Well, that's one of the places that is using `ThreadContext.FromCurrent`. If you mean in your real code, I'm afraid you'll have to figure it out  yourself - there are a lot of internal calls to that method in order to be traced just by looking at the code. Again, check a calls to `Application` after the normal `Exit` call.

Comment: @IvanStoev The call to `MessageLoop` was to demonstrate your point that any call to `FromCurrent` will attach a new `ThreadContext` to the current thread if it doesn't already have a non-Disposed one. The behavior of the question can be duplicated by either using the close button (2 events) or the added button which calls `Application.Exit()` (1 event). There is something unique to the execution path of calling `Form.Close()` which causes a new `ThreadContext` without a `MessageLoop` to be attached some time after it caused the first one  with a `MessageLoop` to be disposed.

Comment: @PeterDuniho Interesting development. I tried to enable .Net source stepping and now the behavior no longer occurs in debug build but still occurs in release builds. Turning off source stepping does **not** restore previous behavior of debug builds.

Comment: I just realized that your comment meant that the use of the MessageLoop property is what causes the behavior. I thought that was just part of a "uncomment this to see it doesn't change anything", but re-read it and understand better now. Uncommenting, I get the same behavior in debug and release, using C# 5.

Comment: By "same behavior" I mean, I can reproduce the issue you describe if I uncomment that line. I agree with @Ivan that this appears to be a normal consequence of accessing that property. I see the event raised only one time without accessing that property and closing the form with the button.

Comment: @PeterDuniho Just to clarify, "...with the button." If that's the added button with the `Application.Exit()` call in the handler then yes it only happens once. The double event happens when the CloseButton (X - button, CloseBox, whatever it's proper name is) is used to close the form.

Comment: Even when I click the close box, I still only see the event happen once. Release build.

Comment: Well that's my behavior now as well. Only thing changed was enabling stepping through .net code. Disabling that did not restore behavior. Won't have a chance to test this "fix" on a second box.